# How to capture react-native logs in ios application and print them

Tags: ios, react-native

How to capture react-native logs in ios application  and print them

Comment: Can You be A Bit More Specific? You Can Use Console.log() Command To Log The Details ... I Think You Are Referring To This One

Comment: I want to capture react-native logs inside an application and form an array to display to end user